# can not add another variable in form-submit-script in php with ".\n\n"

Tags: php, html, forms, syntax

I made a script to send a html-form thru php.
This codepiece is working:

```
$txt="Mail from: ".$name.".\n\n".$telefon; 
mail($mailTo, $subject,  $txt, $headers);
```

If I extend `$txt` with one more variable it is not working:

```
$txt="Mail from: ".$name.".\n\n".$telefon".\n\n".$message; 
mail($mailTo, $subject,  $txt, $headers);
```

```
Error in editor is: syntax error, unexpected t_constant_encapsed_string
serverlog says: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected double-quoted string ".\n\n" in line 13
```

Quotes can not be the problem, not working with ' either.

Why is one `".\n\n"` ok, but one more variable added with 2nd `".\n\n"` not ok?
If I skip 2nd `".\n\n"` the longer string is working. But I want a 2nd line break.

Thank you!

Just wanted to extend $txt alike the syntax before. Now the syntax for adding another ".\n\n" seems different.

Comment: You're missing the concatenation operator `.` between `$telefon` and the second `".\n\n"`

Comment: It's much easier if you use variable interpolation instead of concatenation: `$txt="Mail from: $name.\n\n$telefon.\n\n$message";`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing a concatenation operator (the dot symbol) between the $telefon variable and the following string in your second code snippet. This is causing a syntax error in your code.

To fix this, you can add the dot operator between $telefon and ".\n\n". Here's the corrected code:

```
$txt="Mail from: ".$name.".\n\n".$telefon."\n\n".$message; 
mail($mailTo, $subject,  $txt, $headers);
```

Notice the dot operator . after $telefon in the second line.

By adding this operator, you can concatenate $telefon, the ".\n\n" string, and $message into a single string variable, $txt.